# remote access to redis fro google cloud servers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis

I have two servers on google cloud in the same project, and I want remote access to the Redis of the first server, so I comment bind command on redis.conf and add a rule to the firewall to have access on 6379 port, but I can't connect to Redis from the second server. can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to a redis instance depends from where you want to connect, this options could be from Compute Engine VM instances, Google Kubernetes Engine clusters, Cloud Functions, the App Engine flexible environment, and the App Engine standard environment.

In the link below are described the ways to connect with redis from the different sources.
https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance